# Ruby Mysql troubles

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have troubles with mysql gem installation. I performed this in my terminal: 
(I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard)

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
 --with-mysql-config
 --without-mysql-config
 --with-mysql-dir
 --with-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
 --with-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-mlib
 --without-mlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-zlib
 --without-zlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-socketlib
 --without-socketlib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-nsllib
 --without-nsllib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
 --with-mygcclib
 --without-mygcclib
 --with-mysqlclientlib
 --without-mysqlclientlib
```

Gem files will remain installed in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1` for inspection.
Results logged to `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out`

What I have to do next? To have mysql running with my ruby application?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, the correct solution is to install the 64 bit MySQL server version and then reinstall all the gems, specifically the mysql gem.

Answer (score 0):

On Snow Leopard, you have to do:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the following packages:

```
apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```